# ER_CON_COUNT_ERROR: Too many connections Typeorm nestjs

Tags: typeorm, node.js-typeorm, nestjs-typeorm

i am using raw query to execute the command and it is running but i am having a problem because every time it is executed it always creates a new connection, so i get the error "ER_CON_COUNT_ERROR: Too many connections"

here is the code that i made

data-source.ts

```
import { DataSource } from "typeorm";
export class DBDataSource {

   async _mysql(query : string){
        const AppDataSource = new DataSource({
            type: "mysql",
            host: process.env.DATABASE_HOST,
            port: 3306,
            username: process.env.DATABASE_USER,
            password: process.env.DATABASE_PASS,
            database: process.env.DATABASE_NAME,
            synchronize: false,
        })
        
        try {
            if (!AppDataSource.isInitialized) {
                await AppDataSource.initialize();
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error?.message);
        }

        let result =  AppDataSource.query(query);

        return result;
    }
}
```

book.services.ts

```
import { Injectable} from '@nestjs/common';
import { DBDataSource } from '../Config/data-source';

@Injectable()
export class BookService {
  constructor(
    private httpService: HttpService,
    private readonly dbDataSource: DBDataSource
  )  {}

  
  async GET_BookByID(id: string){

    let resbook = await this.dbDataSource._mysql('SELECT * FROM mst_book WHERE id = "'+id+'"');

    return resbook; 
  }
  }
```

I've tried setting up the connection but still can't stop the error. i just want to fix the error with not create new or more connection.

thanks.